# Replacing values with shapes in images

Tags: python-3.x, plot

I'm currently plotting two images. The first image is the RGB image and the second image is the heatmap corresponding to the RGB image. I'm thresholding the heatmap to only display certain values and so far it is working.

However, it is really difficult to see where the values are, as they are only 10 pixels in a 300 by 300 image. I was wondering if it is possible to replace those values with a circle identifier to make it easier to see?

Here is my code to plot the superimposed images:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.imshow(f_rgb_0)
ax1.imshow(np.where((pos_output[0,:,:,0] > thresh_min) & (pos_output[0,:,:,0] < thresh_max),
                    pos_output[0,:,:,0], np.nan), alpha=0.6, cmap=plt.cm.Oranges)
plt.title('Pos Output')
plt.show()
```

Here is the superimposed result:
[image]

You can see the small pixel values near the centre of the remote.

Solved. Here is the code:

```
# Set some threshold for values plot                                                                           
img_flattened = img.reshape(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1])
sorted_img_output = sorted(img_flattened, reverse=True)

# Choose number of points to plot
number_of_points = 10
thresh_min = sorted_img_output[number_of_points]
thresh_max = sorted_img_output[0]

# Values that meet conditions 
locations_of_values = np.where((img_output[0,:,:,0] > thresh_min) & (img_output[0,:,:,0] < thresh_max),
                    img_output[0,:,:,0], np.nan)

locations_of_values = locations_of_values > 0

locations_of_values = np.nonzero(locations_of_values)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.scatter(locations_of_values[1], locations_of_values[0])
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this on your own?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use plot/scatter with the indices of the values. No luck yet.

Comment: Show your attempt please. Right now you have a requirements dump, not a programming question.

Comment: I actually got it to work :D. The above method worked. The code is above for future people.

Comment: Either post your solution as an answer, which you can then select, or possibly consider removing the question entirely.